# Undefined reference to `DSM_ENTRY`

Tags: c++, twain

I was trying to implement Twain Protocol and I got this error in initial
stage only. Can anyone with knowledge of Twain protocol help.

```
#include<twain.h>
#include<kdscust.h>
#include<stddef.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    TW_IDENTITY twIdentity;  
    TW_UINT16 rc;
    TW_IDENTITY  kdk;
    kdk.Id=0;
    kdk.Version.MajorNum=5;
    kdk.Version.MinorNum=5;
    kdk.Version.Language=TWLG_ENGLISH_USA;
    kdk.Version.Country=TWCY_USA;
    strcpy(kdk.Version.Info,"KDS v2.3.8 2017/11/09");
    kdk.ProtocolMajor =2;
    kdk.ProtocolMinor=2;
    kdk.SupportedGroups=DG_CONTROL;
    strcpy(kdk.Manufacturer,"Kodak"); 
    strcpy(kdk.ProductFamily,"Generic");
    strcpy(kdk.ProductName,"Kodak");
    //Opening The Source Manager
    rc = (DSM_Entry)(&kdk,NULL,DG_CONTROL,DAT_PARENT,MSG_OPENDSM,NULL);
    if (rc == TWRC_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Success");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Failure");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's a linker error, how do you build your application?

Answer (score 0):

You have included the header file which contains only the declaration of DSM_Entry.

I'm not really sure but I think one approach would be to call LoadLibrary on the TwainDSM DLL. But I think a more better approach would be to download the sample driver/app from Twain org and build your code using it.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/twain-samples/ . Probably this can help.